# Is there a replacement for Beast for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, beast

An open source project called Beast implemented a forum in about 500 lines of Ruby on Rails code. The project seems to have fallen silent (http://beast.caboo.se/). Is there an open source project that replaces beast and is compatible with the database schema defined for Beast? I have used Beast to sponsor a forum and would like to upgrade and move the deployment from Ubuntu to OS X on a more recent version of Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at altered_beast? [Ground-up rewrite of Beast](http://github.com/technoweenie/altered_beast/tree/master)

Comment: Thx, is there a site for download and that details how to install?

Comment: You should be able to download directly from GitHub. Look for the download button in the gray area at the top of the site, just below the header.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to obtain the source for Beast, try [this SVN tree](http://svn.techno-weenie.net/projects/beast/).